# Displaying the whole row that contains max value for a specific integer type field. Returns error

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I need some help regarding using SQL, I need someone with C#/SQL knowledge, all I need is a simple line or if necessary a whole code that has only one purpose: to display only the row that has the highest number of CLikes in the table Cars inside a Gridview/Label, can anyone provide me such code and teach me? this issue is in regards to web development.

I already tried using some codes that I will provide below, but I always get an error which says mismatch in criteria type or something of the sort.

```
 //this button is inside a masterpage.cs file    
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
 {
     string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("App_Data/DatabaseVSC.accdb");
     localhost.wbCarsDb o = new localhost.wbCarsDb();
     DataSet ds = o.GetMostPopularCar(constr);
     string x  =   (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CLikes"].ToString());
     DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
     ds2 = o.retDetailsCID_datasetR(x,constr);
     this.GridView2.DataSource = ds2;
     this.GridView2.DataBind();
     this.GridView1.DataSource = ds;
     this.GridView1.DataBind();
 }

 //these are codes used in the code above inside the button,  they're stored inside the main CarsDb class that I use to store all crucial codes
 [WebMethod]
 public DataSet GetMostPopularCar(string connectionstr)
 {
     string querystr = string.Format("SELECT MAX(CLikes) AS LargestLike FROM Cars");
     OleDbConnection connectObj = new OleDbConnection(connectionstr);
     OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(querystr, connectObj);
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     da.Fill(ds);
     return ds;
 }

 [WebMethod]
 public DataSet retDetailsCID_datasetR(string CLikes, string connectionstr)
 {
     string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("App_Data/DatabaseVSC.accdb");
     string querystr = string.Format("SELECT [CID] FROM [Cars] WHERE [CLikes]='{0}'", CLikes);
     OleDbConnection connectObj = new OleDbConnection(connectionstr);
     OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(querystr, connectObj);
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     da.Fill(ds);
     return ds;
 }
```

Here's what happens when I activate the button:

> Column 'CLikes' does not belong to table Table.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Column 'CLikes' does not
>   belong to table Table.
>
> Line 26:         localhost.wbCarsDb o = new localhost.wbCarsDb(); 
> Line
>   27:         DataSet ds = o.GetMostPopularCar(constr); 
> Line 28:
>   string x  =   (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CLikes"].ToString()); 
> Line 29:   DataSet ds2 = new DataSet(); // the line 28 is red
>
> Source File: c:\Users\alaas\OneDrive\Email
>   attachments\Documents\School\ComputerProgramming\VintageSportsCars2\MasterPage.master.cs
>   Line: 28

**Stack Trace:**

```
[ArgumentException: Column 'CLikes' does not belong to table Table.]
   System.Data.DataRow.GetDataColumn(String columnName) +5953463
   System.Data.DataRow.get_Item(String columnName) +13
   MasterPage.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\alaas\OneDrive\Email attachments\Documents\School\ComputerProgramming\VintageSportsCars2\MasterPage.master.cs:28
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9782698
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +204
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1639
```

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3282.0

Comment: You have renamed _CLikes_ as _LargestLike_ in your first query. You should use that in your reading from the dataset

Comment: And your second query, if CLikes is a numeric column then you should treat it as a number not converting to a string and using a string to find values in a numeric column

Comment: You can also use 1 query to get the result `SELECT [CID] FROM [Cars] WHERE [CLikes]=(SELECT MAX(CLikes) FROM Cars)`

Comment: @Luuk thanks a lot! I just wanted to ask though, is there a way to display the whole row instead of just the CID in that row?

Comment: The sort answer is `SELECT * FROM [Cars] WHERE ..` will do that, but you should not use that in a program! In stead of the `*`, you should give a comma-separated list of all the field names in that table (the field names that are not know here, because you did not give that info here).

Comment: @Luuk in what form do I type the list? Is it typed in this way for example?:     
SELECT ([Cname], [Cmodel], [Cprice], [Ccolor]) FROM [Cars] WHERE ..

Comment: yep, but without the '(' and the ')'. `SELECT [Cname], [Cmodel], [Cprice], [Ccolor] FROM [Cars] WHERE ...`

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @Steve in the comments -

> You have renamed `CLikes` as `LargestLike` in your first query. You should use that in your reading from the dataset
>
> And your second query, if `CLikes` is a numeric column then you should treat it as a number not converting to a string and using a string to find values in a numeric column.

---

<sub>*I've added this as a Community Wiki so that the question may be resolved without the answers being hidden in comments; all credit to @Steve.*</sub>